# SVN locked in netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans

I keep getting messages like these below whenever I try to `commit`, `update` or whatever.

```
svn: E155004: Working copy 'C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\futurenet\trunk\newproject' locked
svn: E155004: 'C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\NetBeansProjects' is already locked.
```

I tried also to do `cleanup`as other topics suggest but still the same message.
Could someone help me please?

Comment: Tried in GUI way too ? i.e., `Subversion -> Cleanup Working Copy` on Project folder from Netbeans

Comment: I am using only GUI because I am pretty much beginner. Do not know any other ways honestly

Comment: Click on the project folder and  then `Subversion->Cleanup Working Copy` ?

Comment: Yes, it shows me error message that the netbeans project is locked
`org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E155004: Working copy 'C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\project\trunk\newproject' locked
E155004: 'C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\NetBeansProjects' is already locked.`

Comment: Ok, just for testing can you cut and paste the `.svn`  folder to some other location and try out ? It might be hidden folder

Comment: It might be a stupid question but where should I look for svn folder :D?

Comment: It should be in your project folder where you work :)

Comment: Now I see this `org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E155007: 'C:\Users\Mateusz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\project\trunk' is not a working copy directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95031/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-divhelper11).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Why this error raised**

This is because the project folder is closed suddenly (without proper checkout) or some strange reasons like crashes

**How to fix it**

**Way 1 :** By doing `svn cleanup` from the command line

If the way 1 doesn't help

**Way 2 :** You can do a fresh SVN i.e.,

Cut the `.svn` that is inside the project folder to some other location

In `Team->Subversion->Checkout` Do a fresh checkout

Note 1 : You can choose any client such as `Git` or `Mercurial` and proceed the Regular Checkout Process

Note 2 : You can find the `.svn` folder again appeared in your project folder, it means you are done with fresh svn

**Added screen for Reference**

[image: SVN]

Comment: Yes, this does work but it is not a solution it is a remedy. The solution would be for Netbeans to stop file locking so the SVN client can manage the local files without have to break the locks in order to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on windows, but netbeans svn did not help, I used the [tortoise](https://tortoisesvn.net) integrated option, navigated to the parent of the project in explorer right clicked the project folder / select TortoiseSVN / select clean up / check the Break write locks then click OK

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Trying the above it still was not able to break the lock.

Answer (score 0):

SVN locked in netbeans

Try This

1. Right click on locked file
2. go to subversion option
3. then go Working copy option
4. then finally click on cleanup option

I hope this will solve issue 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans, it's work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi2ZR.png) solution with Tortoise is better than others.